# Python JVM Flask

Tags: python, flask, jvm

I created a simple API using Flask, in some methods I need to use jvm like this:

```
@app.route('/inference', methods=['POST'])
def inference():   
     jvm.start()

     #do somethings     

     jvm.stop()
     return something
```

but if i make my method this way, every time I call the API the server starts and stops jvm, it's very slow.

My question is where can a put the call `jvm.start()` for using in my methods without starting and stopping jvm every time I call API?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`before_first_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) decorator in flask:

> Registers a function to be run before the first request to this instance of the application.
>
> The function will be called without any arguments and its return value is ignored.

---

You could create a function to start JVM and register this function by using the decorator:

```
@app.before_first_request
def start_jvm():
    jvm.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

just use `before_first_request` as per Yuan JI answer. If you want to cleanup or manually stop the jvm you can use [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#module-atexit). It will run once the app is terminated.

eg:

```
@atexit.register
def onend():    
    jvm.stop()
```